# How to set the items in a ChoiceBox

Tags: scalafx

I have a ChoiceBox that I want to set with an ObservableList. In JavaFX I might do:

```
ObservableList genres = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
  "Chamber",
  "Country",
  "Cowbell",
  "Metal",
  "Polka",
  "Rock"
);

choiceBox.setItems(genres);
```

But I can't find any equivalent examples in ScalaFX. What would that look like?

Answer (score 0):

ScalaFX prides wrappers for JavaFX collections that are compatible with Scala collections. You can do following:

```scala
  var genres = ObservableBuffer(
    "Chamber",
    "Country",
    "Cowbell",
    "Metal",
    "Polka",
    "Rock"
  )

  choiceBox.items = genres
```

You will find more example in ProScalaFX project: https://github.com/scalafx/ProScalaFX